# Let's encrypt allows only one vhost per file on ubuntu/apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, phusion-passenger, lets-encrypt

Currently I am trying to set up let's encrypt on my Ubuntu 16.04 server.
I am using Apache 2.4.18 as my webserver and also passenger.

I am using the following command to generate my certs and to configure the apache files:

> letsencrypt -d example.com --apache

https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-apache

But letsencrypt gives me the following error message:

> Currently, we only support configuration with one vhost per file in
>   apache2.conf

The problem is that I only have one vhost configured. I didn't change too many things in the file, but that may be the problem.

I only insert the vhost tag (which only appears once in my file)

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80> # I am not using wildcard but my IP instead
    ServerName www.mydomain.com

    Alias /sub /var/...
    <Location /sub>
        PassengerBaseUri /sub
        PassengerAppRoot /var/..
    </Location>
    <Directory /var/..>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you need more information from my .conf file?

I have to admit that I am new to such things and have no idea where my mistake is. I do not include other files and I checked all my vhosts with

> apache2ctl -S

and there was only one. I believe that the error message isn't 100% correct and the reason why letsencrypt fails is something different than my vhost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods to verify domain ownership.  You may want to use a different method of verifying domain ownership such as `--webroot` or `--standalone`